# Is it natural to use the word "fast" to say that someone arrived earlier than expected?

Tags: word-usage

Was the word *fast* used naturally in the following contex?

> The guy is **fast** today. Usually he is late for work.

If it isn't natural, what would be a natural way to say it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in that context.  The usual word would be "early".

Fast, or quick, point to qualities of speed. Usually fast and quick mean the same.  But the guy might have been very slow, but simply woke up earlier than usual. So unlike some languages, in which the same word can be used for "early" and "fast", this isn't the case in English: Fast refers to the speed of motion, Early refers to the time of arrival, and they aren't synonymous.

Answer (score 3):

As James said, not in that context so much...

But, depending on context, let's say you just got off the phone with the person and then they show up at work more quickly than you expected... you might say to them "Well *that* was fast." (Referring to the amount of time between finishing the phone call and seeing them.)

But if you're referring to a person who is typically late, the opposite of late is early. (Or if one wanted to be particularly sarcastic, one might refer to that person being "on time")